# Understanding a part of the proof of Cauchy's theorem in the abelian case

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

> (Cauchy's theorem in the abelian case): If $G$ is a finite abelian group such that $p \ | \  |G|$, where $p$ is a prime, then $\exists g \in G$ such that $o(g) = p$.

Basically the part of the proof that I'm stuck on is the following. After choosing an $h \in G$ for which $h \neq 1_G$ and assuming $o(h) = l$, we form the subgroup $ H = \langle h \rangle$. We can then form the quotient group $G / H$ which has order $$|G/H| = \frac{|G|}{|H|} = \frac{|G|}{l}$$ by Lagrange's theorem. The next part of the proof says that $p$ divides $\frac{|G|}{l}$ because $p$ divided $|G|$, and I can't immediately see why this is the case.

What I think is that this part of the proof must be using some argument from elementary number theory, and I think that the theorem that's being referenced must be (similar to) the following conjecture of mine:

> Conjecure: If $p$ is prime and $p \ | \ x$ and $\frac{x}{l} = m$ where $m, l \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $p \ | \ m$.

In trying to prove the above this is as far as I got.

*Attempted Proof:* Since $p | x$ there exists an $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $pn =x$, Then $$\frac{x}{l } = m \implies \frac{pn}{l} = m \implies pn = ml$$ and since $p$ divides the left hand side of the above equation it follows that the right hand side of the equation must also be divisible by $p$. So $p|ml$ and since $p$ is prime $p|l$ or $p|m$. If $p|m$ we are done, if $p|l$ then...

---

And that's as far as I got. Is the above conjecture actually a theorem? If so is it the one being used in Cauchy's theorem and if so how could I finish proving the above conjecture?

Comment: I think your doubt is just about the reasoning of the proof. Notice that if $l$ is a multiple of $p$ then you have a candidate for $g$. Indeed, we have that if $l = rp$ then taking $g = rh$ has order $p$. On the other hand, if $p$ does not divide $l$ then using the argument above you obtain a group $G' = G/H$ of smaller order, precisely $|G|/l$ and you still have $p \mid |G'|$..

Answer (score 0):

It is not true in general. Obviously $3|6$ but $3$ doesn't divide $\frac{6}{3}=2$. What is that $l$ that appears in the proof? It can't be just any number.

Comment: $H$ is normal because $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Oh, right. I didn't see $G$ is abelian. I guess that's why the proof is so strange. I'm used to see proofs of Cauchy's theorem for general finite groups.

Answer (score 0):

When defining the $h$ and $l$, you may also assume $l$ is not divisible by $p$. (For otherwise you are already done.)

The remaining is just elementary number theory.